# Show row in a series even if the data is missing from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need a SQL query to return a row for every month in years 2015 and 2016 for every company that pays dues.  The resulting dataset will show which months the company didn't pay dues by a null value.  The problem is that if they didn't pay dues they won't have an entry in the database so no row will appear for than month.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT 
case when n.co_id <>'' then n.co_id else n.ID end ID
,su.CONTINUOUS_SINCE
,n.COMPANY
,a.EFFECTIVE_DATE
, a.AMOUNT


FROM dbo.Name n
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Activity a ON n.ID = a.ID 
inner JOIN dbo.Loc_Info l ON n.ID = l.ID
inner JOIN dbo.Segment_Categories s ON l.CURRENT_SEGMENT = s.CODE
inner JOIN dbo.Subscriptions su on su.id=n.id

WHERE    a.PRODUCT_CODE='rental' and n.MEMBER_TYPE in ('rb','rl') and a.EFFECTIVE_DATE Between '2015-07-01' And GetDate() AND a.ACTIVITY_TYPE='dues'
order by case when n.co_id <>'' then n.co_id else n.ID end, EFFECTIVE_DATE asc
```

If the company has paid every month it works out fine but the point is to find the companies that haven't paid so suppose Company XYZ paid every month in 2015 except June I need a row for June for Company XYZ that has a NULL value or a zero or some other indicator that they missed a payment.  As it stands now the row is simply omitted because the data isn't there and it is hard to find a missing row out of thousands or rows.

I realize it is probably a different type of join or something but I am just not getting it to work out.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry.  SQL 2012.  Specifically 12.0.2000.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Generate all the months from 1 to 12 with a recursive cte.

2) Get all months years and companies combinations with a `cross join`.

3) `left join` on this result-set to show missing months.

```
with months as (select 1 mth
                union all
                select mth+1 from months where mth<12)
,yearmonthscompanies as (select * 
                         from months m
                         cross join (select 2015 yr union all select 2016 yr) y
                         cross join (select distinct id,co_id,company from name) c 
                        )  
SELECT 
case when ymc.co_id <>'' then ymc.co_id else ymc.ID end ID
,su.CONTINUOUS_SINCE
,ymc.COMPANY
,coalesce(a.effective_date,datefromparts(ymc.yr,ymc.mth,1)) as effective_date
,coalesce(a.AMOUNT,0) amount
FROM yearmonthscompanies ymc
LEFT JOIN dbo.Name n ON n.co_id=ymc.co_id and n.id=ymc.id and n.company=ymc.company
LEFT JOIN dbo.Activity a ON n.ID = a.ID and a.PRODUCT_CODE='rental' 
and n.MEMBER_TYPE in ('rb','rl') and a.EFFECTIVE_DATE Between '2015-07-01' and GetDate() 
and a.ACTIVITY_TYPE='dues' 
and year(a.effective_date) = ymc.yr and month(a.effective_date) = ymc.mth
inner JOIN dbo.Loc_Info l ON n.ID = l.ID
inner JOIN dbo.Segment_Categories s ON l.CURRENT_SEGMENT = s.CODE
inner JOIN dbo.Subscriptions su on su.id=n.id
order by case when ymc.co_id <>'' then ymc.co_id else ymc.ID end
,effective_date
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked well.  I have only used cross joins a few times in the past and wasn't too comfortable with them.  I made a few tweaks to your query but only because you didn't have all the details when you wrote it but I only had to add one line of code to it and it worked like a charm and solved my issue expertly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dummy table for the months, left join the `dbo.Activity` to it, that way you'll get all the months, and then join that to `dbo.Name`

Comment: Thanks, this solution did work as well as vkp's solution.  I went with his because it was less code overall and executed a little bit faster, however your solution was effective as well.  Thanks for the help.